# Finding service URL of WMS for bathymetry data?

Tags: data, wms, bathymetry

I don't seem to find the link to download the bathymetry data from this site.

https://www.geoseaportal.de/gdi-bsh-portal/ui

Comment: https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/StaticInformation_BathymetryContours/guest?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around on that site (assisted by Google Translate) I came to [this page](https://gdiwiki.bsh.de/wiki/index.php/Bathymetry_Contours) which gave me the URL for WMS requests -

> https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/StaticInformation_BathymetryContours/guest?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

pasting that into the `Add WMS` wizard for QGis gave me a bathymetry contour map of the world.

Comment: This link has since died